# C# Stream Dictionary issue

Tags: c#, sockets, dictionary, socket.io

Send - Socket.send(ToSend);

```
public static byte[] ToSend() {
    Dictionary<int, int> D = new Dictionary<int, int>() { {1,10},{2,88} };
    List<int> L = new List<int>() { {22}, {44} };
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var mStream = new MemoryStream();
    binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, D);
    //binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, L);
    return mStream.ToArray();
}
```

Receive - (with async) if (Socket.EndReceive(ar) > 0){Load(bytes);}

```
public static void Load(byte[] bytes) {
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        mStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var myObject = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as Dictionary<int, int>;
        //var myObject = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as List<int>;
        Console.WriteLine(">> " + myObject[1]);
    }
```

Problem: List is working fine but Dictionary not, throwing exception like: 
"Before the analysis was finished, the end of the stream was encountered." 
Can someone tell me why? Where is the problem? Hashtables also work with above code. Why Dictionarys don't ?

EDIT: Send is on client side called just after connected with simple send(); just for testing.

```
socket.Send(ToSend());
```

Receiving is on server side with:

```
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.RecMessage), this);
```

RecMessage looks like this:

```
if (socket.EndReceive(result) > 0) {Message Msg = new Message(buffer);}
```

In Message is simple:

```
Public Message(byte[] buffer){Load(buffer);}
```

Hashtables are working, Lists are working, Int, String, or whatever I use is working but not Dictionaries. Maybe is some problem with Begin and End Receive?

EDIT2: changed buffer to [2048] solved the issue so problem is with begining and edning receiving. How it should be constructed in properly?

Comment: This works for me without async, are you perhaps calling Load(...) before ToSend(...) completed? It could explain why List works and Dictionary doesnt as the List seralizes to 221 bytes and 1369 bytes and most likely completes sealizing slower; theres to little information to know for sure, can you show the context of how you use ToSend(...) and Load(...)

Comment: You're assuming that one Send() corresponds to one Receive(). It doesn't. You need to invent a framing protocol, or rather, use a higher-level construct than sockets. Look at Protocol Buffers (protobuf-net).

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved. I've added prefix when sending and buffer manager when receiving:

```
    const int PrefixSize = 4;
    bool prefixSet = false;
    public int DataSize = 0; 
    int RecLength = 0;
    byte[] Received = new byte[2048];

       try {
            int dataRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (dataRead > 0) {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, Received, RecLength , dataRead);
                RecLength += dataRead;
                if (RecLength >= PrefixSize) {
                    if (!prefixSet) {
                        prefixSet = true;
                        DataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(Received, 0);
                    }
                    if (RecLength >= DataSize) {
                        RecLength = 0; prefixSet = false; 
                        byte[] data = new byte[DataSize];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(Received, 4, data, 0, DataSize);
                        ReceiveNextMessage();
                        Message m = new Message(this, data);
                    }
                    else {
                        ReceiveNextMessage();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    ReceiveNextMessage();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Maybe someone find ths useful.